# How to implement filter and basic authentication in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my project I use django rest framework. To filter the results I use django_filters backend. There is my code:

models.py

```
class Robot(models.Model):
    robot = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    short_Description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    parameter = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    jenkins_job = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='JenkinsJobName')
    jenkins_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='JenkinsToken')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.robot

class assignParameter(models.Model): 
    parameterName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    assignRobot= models.ForeignKey(Robot, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='param', blank=True, null=True)

class jenkinsHistory(models.Model):
    jenkinsJobName = models.ForeignKey(Robot, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='JenkinJobName', blank=True, null=True)
    jenkinsBuildNumber = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    jenkinsBuildStatus = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    errorMsg = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    Param = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True, null=True)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
from hello.models import Robot,assignParameter,jenkinsHistory
from rest_framework import serializers

class assignParameterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = assignParameter
        fields = ['id', 'parameterName', 'assignRobot']

class jenkinsHistorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    jenkinsJobName = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True, slug_field='robot')
    class Meta: 
        model = jenkinsHistory
        # list_serializer_class = FilteredAssessmentsSerializer
        fields = ['id','jenkinsJobName','jenkinsBuildNumber','jenkinsBuildStatus','errorMsg','Param']

class RobotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    param = assignParameterSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    # JenkinJobName = jenkinsHistorySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta: 
        model = Robot
        fields = ['id', 'robot', 'short_Description', 'status', 'parameter', 'jenkins_job', 'jenkins_token', 'param']
```

and here's my **view.py**:

```
from requests import api
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.filters import SearchFilter
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from hello.models import Robot,jenkinsHistory
from hello.api.serializers import RobotSerializer, jenkinsHistorySerializer

@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def robot_list_api_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        rb = Robot.objects.all()
        serializer = RobotSerializer(rb, many=True)
        filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
        filterset_fields = ['robot']
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        return Response("You can do anything here")

@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def robot_history_api_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        rh = jenkinsHistory.objects.all()
        serializer = jenkinsHistorySerializer(rh, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        return Response("You can do anything here")
```

and that's my two response
[image]
[image]

How can i use filter and basic auth here so that i can get the filtered value?
I want URL/?robot=Demo this type and also URL/?id filtered data
and want basic auth like this code

```
authentication_classes = [BasicAuthentication]
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

But it is not working in my view . how to get the filtered data and basic auth here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using custom filter I achieve the filtration in function based view
here's the code of my view

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, authentication_classes, permission_classes
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from rest_framework.permissions import  IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.authentication import BasicAuthentication



class RobotFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Robot
        fields = ['robot']

@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
@authentication_classes([BasicAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def robot_list_api_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        rb = Robot.objects.all()
        filterset = RobotFilter(request.GET, queryset=rb)
        if filterset.is_valid():
            queryset = filterset.qs
        serializer = RobotSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        return Response("You can do anything here")
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables you defined in your function-based view e.g. `filter_backends`, `filterset_fields`, etc. are meant to be used as attributes for the class-based drf-views only as [documented](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#attributes).

Change your function-based view to class-based view from:

```
@api_view(["GET", "POST"])
def robot_list_api_view(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        rb = Robot.objects.all()
        serializer = RobotSerializer(rb, many=True)
        filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
        filterset_fields = ['robot']
        return Response(serializer.data)
    elif request.method == "POST":
        return Response("You can do anything here")
```

To:

```
from rest_framework import generics


class RobotListApiView(generics.ListAPIView)
    queryset = Robot.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RobotSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['robot']
```

The [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend) has a nice example on this:

> ```
> class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):
>     queryset = Product.objects.all()
>     serializer_class = ProductSerializer
>     filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
>     filterset_fields = ['category', 'in_stock']
> ```

---

It has to be class-based view because as [documented](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#generic-views):

> One of the key benefits of **class-based views** is the way they allow you
> to compose bits of reusable behavior. REST framework takes advantage
> of this by providing a number of pre-built views that provide for
> commonly used patterns.
>
> **The generic views provided by REST framework allow you to quickly build API views that map closely to your database models.**

If you would really need to use function-based views, then you have to do things manually (like manually writing the code to filter the results) because as said above, pre-built views that maps to database operations such as listing/filtering of records is implemented via class-based views. You are limited to this [API decorators](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api-policy-decorators) if using function-based views.

Comment: But i want that function based only for my coding requirements. Is there any way to implement those in function based view?

Comment: I updated my answer. Please see last part.

Comment: can you please help how to do filter manually in function based view?